# While loop with delay not working as intended

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to create a button that initiates a countdown, but during the countdown the button 'image' changes in relation to the amount of seconds passed (e.g. 3 - new button, 2 - new button, 1 - new button). I believe what I've got thus far to be the most efficient way of achieving this.

However, when run there is no image change and no wait before the next iteration of the loop.  The code is in Swift 3.0, and is as follows (left out all initialisation etc.):

```
var countDown = ["buttonThree", "buttonTwo", "buttonOne", "buttonRelease", "buttonMain"]

//The Button in its initial state
@IBAction func playBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var imageCounter:Int = 0
    //Begin Loop
    while imageCounter != 3 {
        let playBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
        playBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: countDown[imageCounter]), for: .normal)
        imageCounter = imageCounter + 1
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { (timer) in }
        print("Working")
    }
    //Delay on third iteration
    if imageCounter == 3 {
        //Execute recording
        _ = DispatchTime.now() + 5
    }

    //Return to normal state after 5 second delay
    let playBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
    playBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: countDown[4]), for: .normal)


}
```

Comment: You can't use a `while` loop since that will block the main queue; which is what you need to use to update the UI.  Rather, schedule a repeating timer and in the timer's closure or handler function display the next label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot wrong with this code. I will try to explain, but you really should go back to your books and actually learn the basics. You got the syntax right, but what you are writing doesn’t make any sense.

Also since you mentioned that you believe this is the most efficient way: Don’t worry about performance or efficiency right now. The most important thing to learn is to write *correct* programs, you can worry about efficiency when you got this. And even then don’t worry too much, you should only optimise after you actually *measured* the performance.

### So lets first take a look whats wrong

```
var countDown = ["buttonThree", "buttonTwo", "buttonOne", "buttonRelease", "buttonMain"]
```

You should use `let` here, unless you are planning to change this array.

```
//The Button in its initial state
@IBAction func playBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
```

The name of your function is no good. Swift style doesn’t use abbreviations like `Btn`, you can spell out `Button`. But even `playButton` is not a good name here, it doesn’t say what this method is good for. A better name would be `playPushed` or maybe just `play`.

```
    var imageCounter:Int = 0
    //Begin Loop
    while imageCounter != 3 {
```

While this style of loop does work, and there is not exactly anything wrong with it, the idiomatic swift way would use a `for in` loop. Also the "begin loop" comment is not necessary, it's obvious that a loop starts here - you see it from the `while` keyword.

```
        let playBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
        playBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: countDown[imageCounter]), for: .normal)
```

Of course your button doesn’t change the image. Here you create a new button, set it’s image and discard the button. This button never gets displayed, unless you add it to the view hierarchy. But that wouldn’t make sense here either - you want to change the current button, not add a new one.

You already have the right button available here, this is what the `sender` parameter is.

```
        imageCounter = imageCounter + 1
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { (timer) in }
```

Timers don’t work like this - they execute the passed closure after the time has elapsed, they don’t pause the current thread for a given time. Your closure (the `{ (timer) in }` part) just does nothing.

```
        print("Working")
    }
    //Delay on third iteration
    if imageCounter == 3 {
        //Execute recording
        _ = DispatchTime.now() + 5
```

This also does not do what you think. This is no delay, it just calculates a time point 5 seconds in the future which you then ignore via the `_ =` part.

```
    }

    //Return to normal state after 5 second delay
    let playBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
    playBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: countDown[4]), for: .normal)
```

Again, you are not updating the button in your UI, but create a new one which you then throw away.

```
}
```

### So how can we fix this?

There are many ways how this can be written. The easiest way that also keeps the shape of your code would be to start multiple timers in your loop with different delays for each change.

```
@IBAction
func playPushed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    sender.isEnabled = false
    let lastCountDownButton = 3
    for (offset, imageName) in countdown[0...lastCountDownButton].enumerated() {
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval(offset), repeats: false) { _ in
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: imageName), for: .normal)

            if offset == lastCountDownButton {
                // Execute recording

                _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: false) { _ in
                    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: countdown[4]), for: .normal)
                    sender.isEnabled = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made one small change by also disabling the button until the whole process is done. Otherwise the user could start the whole sequence multiple times leading to unexpected behaviour.

Instead of the `while` loop I also use a `for in` loop for an subarray `countdown[0...lastCountDownButton]`. The `enumerated()` function returns a new sequence that contains the offset (counted from 0 up) in addition to the actual item.

In a real app I’d write this different though. I’d encapsulate the whole logic in a state machine that gets driven by a single timer.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to comment. I realise my knowledge of the basics is pretty lack lustre, this was probably too ambitious for a second project. But lesson learned, and I'll implement your comment into my code just to study the syntax and logic. Thanks :)